# Paseto example with Graphql(Lighthouse Laravel)

Tags: laravel, security, laravel-lighthouse, paseto

I am looking for a paseto example with Graphql(Lighthouse Laravel) or how to create paseto's for each resource using the user roles and types. Or how to restrict access to only specific resources.

I only found this:

- [Paseto presentation Okta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ai7PVLl4Wng)
- [Paseto docs](https://github.com/paragonie/paseto/tree/master/docs/02-PHP-Library)
- [Paseto Lumen Example](https://github.com/mstaack/lumen-api-starter/blob/master/app/Extensions/Authentication/PasetoAuthGuard.php)

Update: I create a request for paseto implementation in PHP Lighthouse, if you like this idea please give a thumbs up so that this request can get noticed and implemented. Thank you, the request is [here](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/issues/1430)

Thanks in advance for any direction or info